# How can I show alert dialog on base of a stream in case network request fails

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bloc

Here goes the code I have so far.
`_mBlock.mSpotStream` is a network request.
I am interested how can I show alert dialog in case `_mBlock.getSpots()` fails with a network error, while keeping list on screen. I have tried returning alert dialog as a widget, but in this case I can't close it.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(Strings.of(context).spot_list_title), centerTitle: true),
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Stack(
            children: [
              StreamBuilder<List<SpotDto>>(
                stream: _mBlock.mSpotStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return RefreshIndicator(
                    onRefresh: () {
                      return _mBlock.getSpots();
                    },
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                      itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                        return SpotListItem(snapshot.data[position], () {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(position.toString())));
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: StreamBuilder<Progress<bool>>(
                      stream: _mBlock.mStateStream,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        return Visibility(
                          visible: snapshot.data?.mIsLoading ?? false,
                          child: SizedBox.expand(
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(Dimens.overlayOpacity),
                              child: Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ))
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, SpotListBlock block) {
  StreamBuilder<Error<String>>(
    stream: block.mErrorStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(Strings.of(context).error),
          content: Text(snapshot.data.mErrorMessage),
          actions: [
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Cancel"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, true);
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      } else {
        return Row();
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I have fixed it like this, it was the only way I was able to fix this, any reviews are appreciated:
My fix is based on this gist https://gist.github.com/felangel/75f1ca6fc954f3672daf7962577d56f5

```
class SpotListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final SpotListBlock _mBlock = SpotListBlock();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(Strings.of(context).spot_list_title), centerTitle: true),
      body: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Stack(
            children: [
              StreamBuilder<List<SpotDto>>(
                stream: _mBlock.mSpotStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return RefreshIndicator(
                    onRefresh: () {
                      return _mBlock.getSpots();
                    },
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                      itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                        return SpotListItem(snapshot.data[position], () {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(position.toString())));
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              StreamBuilder<Error<String>>(
                stream: _mBlock.mErrorStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        barrierDismissible: false,
                        builder: (_) {
                          return Scaffold(
                            body: Center(
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                child: Text('dismiss'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    });
                    return Container(
                      width: 0.0,
                      height: 0.0,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container(
                      width: 0.0,
                      height: 0.0,
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: StreamBuilder<Progress<bool>>(
                      stream: _mBlock.mStateStream,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        return Visibility(
                          visible: snapshot.data?.mIsLoading ?? false,
                          child: SizedBox.expand(
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(Dimens.overlayOpacity),
                              child: Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ))
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

bloc code

```
Future<List<SpotDto>> getSpots() {
    var completer = new Completer<List<SpotDto>>();
    _reportsRepositoryImpl.getSpots().single.then((spotList) {
      addNewSpotsToList(spotList);
      completer.complete(spotList);
    }).catchError((Object obj) {
      switch (obj.runtimeType) {
        case DioError:
          _mErrorSink.add(Error((obj as DioError).message));
          completer.complete();
          break;
        default:
          completer.complete();
      }
      _mSpotSink.add(_mSpotList);
    });

    return completer.future;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Showing an alert dialog is just a simple call, e.g.:

```
await showDialog<bool>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: 'alert!!!',
        content: 'hello world',
        actions: [
            FlatButton(child: Text('cancel'), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false)),
            FlatButton(child: Text('ok'), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true)),
        ],
      );
    },
  )
```

when you call `showDialog` a dialog will be shown on the screen.

Comment: But will it keep the list on the screen this way? Also when I was adding dialog like this I was unable to lose it with Navigator.pop(context, true)

Comment: @Void of course the original content will be on screen. why cannot Navigator.pop work? could you please give more details?

Comment: Or, there are two things that I still don't understand.
1) My dialog show different content depending on the error(added to the question)
2) Have no idea, why pop is not working, onTap is triggered, but dialog stays on screen

Comment: @Void please give more details... e.g. your full code

Comment: @Void I look at your new code. Notice that **please call showDialog**, NOT **return** a dialog object!

Comment: @Void Please look at the doc of `showDialog`. Firstly follow some tutorials, then go back to your code and I think you will get it :) https://coflutter.com/flutter-how-to-show-dialog/ , https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html

Comment: Thanks, with your help I was finally able to describe the issue, if I am calling showDialog in a StreamBuilder it says that its not a Widget, and streem builder should return a widget. So I can't use it, or I should somehow change it.

Comment: @Void Great! I see your code and it looks reasonable :)